# Postman: Is it possible to stop a postman call from being executed based on conditions detected in pre-requisite scripts?

Tags: postman

I am using the pre-request script in the first call to dynamically generate essential environment variables for the entire script. I also want the users to be notified of those failures when running via collection runner without having to look up to the console. Is it possible to generate information in tests or some other alternative so failures are explicit in the collection runner results?

e.g. if the ip has not been provided in the environment, it does not make sense to run the login call. So i would like to write in a pre-requisite script:

```
if (!environment['IP']) {
    //do not execute any further and do not send the REST call
}
```

I tried using:

```
if (!environment["xyz"]) {
    tests["condtion1"]=false
}
```

but it gives the error:

```
There was an error in evaluating pre-requisite script: tests is not defined
```

Is there any workaround - I don't want to move this code to the tests tab as I don't want to clutter the code there with unrelated environment conditioning.

Comment: When you say you want users to be notified in case of test failure, do you mean some sort of notification in the postman app, or an external notification (email/webhook call)?

Comment: I mean in the report generated after execution within the collection runner environment.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A throw works just fine. (Updated with excellent tip from @Joe White)

```
if (!environment['X']) {
    throw new Error('No "X" set')
}
```

This prevents the REST call from going through.
But in the collection runner mode it stops the entire test suite.

But when coupled with newman collection runner it works just fine.

Comment: This doesn't display the string - it displays "undefined: undefined". It'd be better to throw an Error object instead of a string. `throw new Error('No "X" set')` will display a meaningful message: "Error: No "X" set".

Comment: Im wondered that after several years there is no better official way how to stop request. Throwing error shows many red lines in collection runner. In many other softwares pre-request script usually can stop continuing such us in git pre-commit script we can stop commit if we want what is expected. But postman pre-request script does not have this base feature. So for me pre-request script in postman is useless without this feature.

Comment: yes @mikep - would have been great though - probably can be achieved by updating the url on runtime to a dummy call that returns nothing (valid stub call that returns 200 OK code with blank body in no time) and avoiding the tests by an env var raised from pre-req script as a workaround - this can then be incorporated in the common script area at collection/folder level to remove redundancy - you'd still need to do the same for all collections/folders.

Answer (score 1):

A throw error works fine with this test:

```
var value = pm.environment.get('X')

if (value == undefined || value == null || value.length == 0) {
    throw new Error('No "X" set!')
}
```