# What's the "best practice" in Postman to prevent a destructive API call in production

Tags: postman

We have many "dangerous" API calls and we have lots (>20) environments. Our developers switch between environments all the time.

I want to create an "are you sure?" type of prompt for certain API calls in certain environments.

Initial Idea - for destructive API calls, the pre-request script would check an environment variable and prompt if "Prod".  But there no "prompt" function in Postman that I can find.

Besides suggesting that we don't allow developers in production environments can anyone think of a way to prompt before submission or at least reduce the risk of mistakenly submitting a destructive call to a production env?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wish I didn't have people problems, but I do.   Thanks to everyone telling to make the problem go away.   If anyone has a technical solution for prompting "are you sure" in a production environment, I would very much appreciate hearing about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to solve this with a technical solution, use authentication for your dangerous endpoints. And don't give the credentials to anyone you don't trust. If it's really a problem, you can rotate the credentials.

Or, rotate the staff out of their positions if they can't handle having production access. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a technical solution to avoid accidental calls, I've written a simple pre-request script to only allow GET requests in our production environment (unless you pass in a certain header to override the lock). My aim was only to add some kind of check to ensure we don't accidentally make certain calls in certain environmens..

We wanted to avoid having a situation where someone on the team accidentally made POST or other types of modifying requests against prod. It could easily happen if you're not paying attention to what environment you have selected in postman. Happens to the best of us ‍♂️

The script can be easily modified to block all calls to production if that's what you want :) would have been awesome to have a prompt, but this has to do for now.

*The current solution is to throw an error if certain conditions are met so that the request is not executed.*

Hope this helps anyone else having the same issue:

https://www.fullstackdev.cloud/posts/using-pre-request-scripts-in-postman-to-avoid-dangerous-api-calls

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling here, as of now there is no "prompt" function, its requested on this thread https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/285.

Therefore, the best way to mitigate the risk is to just stop the request itself by throwing an error if the environment variables matches.

Example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47150325/12295149:

```
if (!environment['X']) {
    throw new Error('No "X" set')
}
```